# GREP matching 6-7 digits within other data

Tags: grep, regular-expression, macos

I am trying to create a Regular Expression that will match a string of digits that is 6 or 7 digits long.

[0-9]{6,7} This works but i dont want a match in strings that are longer than 7 digits.

Please see the sample data below with the digits in bold which I need to match.
Some of the 6-7 digit strings have various characters at the beginning and end (new lines, Tabs, spaces) and i also dont want to match strings with two or more 0 at the beginning.

> **1139055**_00000000000000.jpg **1139065**_00000000000000.jpg
>
> 12345678  **1045977**_00000000000000.jpg
>
> _**1162679**.jpg ID:**1099695**_20230615142941.jpg
> **1099692**_20230615142939.jpg
> **1162700**_00000000000000.jpg
> **012456**.psd Title: **0582457**_00_CC 0123456789 Title: **6844393**_50_v2 Title: **6844393**_50_v2.psd 0001456789 0000001546800000
>
> Total: 14
> **6582457**_00_C  **5142090**_00_c Id: **1178287** Title: **6582457**_00_CC Title: **6844393**_50_v2 Id: **1178288** Title: _0042090_00_cc
> __**6771292**_00_cc

Sample input:

```
1139055_00000000000000.jpg 1139065_00000000000000.jpg
12345678 1045977_00000000000000.jpg
_1162679.jpg ID:1099695_20230615142941.jpg 1099692_20230615142939.jpg 1162700_00000000000000.jpg 012456.psd Title: 0582457_00_CC 0123456789 Title: 6844393_50_v2 Title: 6844393_50_v2.psd 0001456789 0000001546800000
Total: 14 6582457_00_C 5142090_00_c Id: 1178287 Title: 6582457_00_CC Title: 6844393_50_v2 Id: 1178288 Title: _0042090_00_cc __6771292_00_cc
```

Expected output:

```
1139055
1139065
1045977
1162679
1099695
1099692
1162700
012456
0582457
6844393
6844393
6582457
5142090
1178287
6582457
6844393
1178288
6771292
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not `1162700`_00000000000000.jpg ? Is this a file ? From where ?

Comment: Why should `1099692_20230615142939.jpg` match and  `1162700_00000000000000.jpg` not?

Comment: @Cyrus Sorry that was a mistake in the mark down which i have fixed just now.

Comment: @GillesQuénot Yes 1162700_00000000000000.jpg is a file but the _ gets added when outputting a contact sheet from an asset management system which is where the text is stripped out of it.

Comment: Question was about the output, where it comes from

Comment: From a contact sheet of images with various text data.

Comment: Please edit question and add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Why should 0042090 not match?

Comment: @Cyrus 0042090 has two or more 0 at the beginning

Comment: For future questions please make sure to provide sample input and expected output as Code Blocks (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to clarify your requirements and so we can copy/paste them to test with. I've done that for you for this one.

Comment: The quoted text you have showing the target strings in bold is useful too in this case, but that's something to provide in **addition to** the input/output as it forces you to insert blank lines when they may not be present in your real input and it doesn't, for example, show us the output format (numbers all on 1 line, or from each input line on separate output lines, or all on their own lines, etc) and without the expected output as a Code Block there's nothing we can copy/paste to `diff` a potential solution's output against to tell if it worked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to summarize, you want to match *two* decimal digits, at least one of which must be non-zero, followed by a further *four or five* decimal digits, not preceded or followed by other digits?

If so, using GNU grep in PCRE mode for the lookarounds:

```
grep -P '(?<!\d)([1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9])[0-9]{4,5}(?!\d)'
```

Testing on your input with `-o`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<!\d)([1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9])[0-9]{4,5}(?!\d)' << \EOF
    1139055_00000000000000.jpg 1139065_00000000000000.jpg

    12345678 1045977_00000000000000.jpg

    _1162679.jpg ID:1099695_20230615142941.jpg 1099692_20230615142939.jpg 1162700_00000000000000.jpg 012456.psd Title: 0582457_00_CC 0123456789 Title: 6844393_50_v2 Title: 6844393_50_v2.psd 0001456789 0000001546800000

    Total: 14 6582457_00_C 5142090_00_c Id: 1178287 Title: 6582457_00_CC Title: 6844393_50_v2 Id: 1178288 Title: _0042090_00_cc __6771292_00_cc
EOF
1139055
1139065
1045977
1162679
1099695
1099692
1162700
012456
0582457
6844393
6844393
6582457
5142090
1178287
6582457
6844393
1178288
6771292
```

Comment: Thank you — this works perfectly on regex101.com but unfortunately i am unable to use it in terminal on macOS.

grep: invalid option -- P

Comment: @pt-t you will note I said "using GNU grep" - you didn't share your OS in the question but you may be able to install GNU grep (as `ggrep`) using `brew`. See for example [How to install and use GNU Grep in macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-install-and-use-gnu-grep-in-macos)

Comment: ... otherwise, you can perhaps convert to perl itself ex. `perl -lne 'print for /(?<!\d)(?:[1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9])[0-9]{4,5}(?!\d)/g'`

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver converting to the perl command works great and no need to install GNU grep.

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to do the job for your example :

```
(?:[^0-9]|^)((?:0[1-9]|[1-9]0|[1-9]{2})[0-9]{4,5})(?:[^0-9]|$)
```

- `(?:[^0-9]|^)` : Ensure its beginning of line or that the character before is not a number
- `((?:0[1-9]|[1-9]0|[1-9]{2})[0-9]{4,5})` : Get the 6-7 digits without 00 at the beginning
- `(?:[^0-9]|$)` : Ensure its end of line or that the character after is not a number

You can play with it on https://regex101.com/r/scZc9q/1

As first/last characters would be in the matched string, the easiest way using `grep` would be to just remove those characters with `sed`:

```shell
grep -oE '([^0-9]|^)(0[1-9]|[1-9]0|[1-9]{2})[0-9]{4,5}([^0-9]|$)' tmp | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex101.com this is close but its also matching _ . and spaces at the beginning and end? I only want the digits.

Comment: The easiest seems to just remove the non-numeric characters with sed, I updated my answer

Comment: That fails to return the second number on the output of `echo 1234567 2345678`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want a simple solution rather than requiring it to be a single regexp, then using GNU awk (which is available or  installable on most Unix boxes) for multi-char `RS`:

```
$ awk -v RS='[^0-9]+' '!/^00/ && /^.{6,7}$/' file
1139055
1139065
1045977
1162679
1099695
1099692
1162700
012456
0582457
6844393
6844393
6582457
5142090
1178287
6582457
6844393
1178288
6771292
```

or using any awk in any shell on every Unix box you could do:

```
awk -F'[^0-9]+' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ( ($i !~ /^00/) && (length($i) ~ /^[67]$/) ) print $i }' file
```

Also with any POSIX awk (which includes the BSD awk on MacOS I believe) for regexp interval `{6,7}` notation, you could use a preceding call to awk to convert all strings of non-digits to newlines so the default `RS` will work afterwards:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/,RS)} 1' file | awk '!/^00/ && /^.{6,7}$/'
```

or, again with any awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/,RS)} 1' file | awk '!/^00/ && (length() ~ /^[67]$/)'
```

You could use `tr -cs '0-9' '\n' < file` or similar instead of `awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/,RS)} 1' file` if you prefer and that works in the version of `tr` you use.

Comment: `tr -cs 0-9 '[\n*]'` would be the POSIX syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This chain of grep, sed and awk provides the list you need:

```
$ egrep '[0-9]*' -o Q768182 | sed '/00/d' | awk 'length>5 && length <8'
1139055
1139065
1045977
1162679
1099695
1099692
012456
0582457
6844393
6844393
6582457
5142090
1178287
6582457
6844393
1178288
6771292
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl` (the `P` in `grep -P` as supported by some `grep` implementations):

```
perl -lne 'print for grep {length() <= 7 && ! /^00/} /\d{6,}/g' your-file
```

With `perl -ln`, `perl` `e`valuates the `e`xpression passed to `-e` for each line of the input.

`/\d{6,}/g` returns a list of all the sequences of `6` or more `\d`igits in the line, and `grep {conditions} from-that` filters the ones that meet the conditions, namely: have a `length` of `7` or less and do not start with `00`.

That could also be written more concisely as:

```
perl -lne 'print for grep {! /^00|.{8}/} /\d{6,}/g'
```

Or even shorter at the expense of legibility:

```
perl -nE'say for grep{!/^00|.{8}/}/\d{6,}/g'
```

Maybe still easier to read than a version using one regexp only (using look-around operators) such as:

```
perl -nE 'say for /(?<!\d)(?!00)\d{6,7}(?!\d)/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*What follows is basically a translation of @StephaneChazelas' excellent (first) Perl answer:*

```
~$ raku -ne '.put for grep { .chars <= 7 && ! /^00/ }, m:g/ \d ** 6..* /;'   file
```

- Above uses Raku's `grep` method, which requires a `,` between the criteria-block: `{ .chars <= 7 && ! /^00/ }`, and the topic: `m:g/ \d ** 6..* /`.
- There is no `length` sub/method/function/routine in Raku. If you want `chars` of a string call `"string".chars` or `$_.chars` or just `.chars` which implies `$_` topic. (If you don't want `.chars` of a string, you may indeed want to call `.elems` instead, i.e. to get back the number of elements of a list, array, etc).
- Otherwise, Raku's `m//` and `s///` and `tr///` operators move all modifiers such as `g` global to the head of the operator, using a preceding `:` colon, i.e. `:g`.
- Finally, enumeration of characters is done with `**` double-star and either an individual integer or range. So whitespace-optional `\d ** 6..*` is the Raku translation of Perl's `\d{6,}`.

*A more linear Raku re-write might instead use the `.grep` routine form, below. Omitting the `.join("\n")` call keeps final returns on their original line, which might be useful for other (similar) problems:*

```
~$ raku -ne '.grep({ .chars <= 7 &&  ! /^00/ }).join("\n").put given m:g/ \d ** 6..* /;'   file
```

*Translating another @StephaneChazelas (Perl) answer:*

```
~$ raku -ne '.put for grep {! / ^00 | .**8 /},  m:g/\d ** 6..* /;'  file
```

---

*Translating @StephaneChazelas answer (original in Perl) that uses lookahead and/or lookbehinds:*

```
~$ raku -ne '.put for m:g/ <!after \d > <!before 00 > \d**6..7 <!before \d> /'   file
```

- In Raku look-aheads and look-behinds are surrounded by `<` `>` angle-brackets.
- In Raku positive is denoted by `?` and negative is denoted by `!`.
- As to using the proper Raku keyword, remember the mnemonic '***ABBA***', meaning  "*for LookAHEADs use `before`, for LookBEHINDs use `after`"*.

---

Sample Input:

```
1139055_00000000000000.jpg 1139065_00000000000000.jpg
12345678 1045977_00000000000000.jpg
_1162679.jpg ID:1099695_20230615142941.jpg 1099692_20230615142939.jpg 1162700_00000000000000.jpg 012456.psd Title: 0582457_00_CC 0123456789 Title: 6844393_50_v2 Title: 6844393_50_v2.psd 0001456789 0000001546800000
Total: 14 6582457_00_C 5142090_00_c Id: 1178287 Title: 6582457_00_CC Title: 6844393_50_v2 Id: 1178288 Title: _0042090_00_cc __6771292_00_cc
```

Sample Output (all four Raku code translations):

```
1139055
1139065
1045977
1162679
1099695
1099692
1162700
012456
0582457
6844393
6844393
6582457
5142090
1178287
6582457
6844393
1178288
6771292
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regexes
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Lookahead_assertions
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Lookbehind_assertions
https://raku.org